# tern auto-complete gives ac-show-menu (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, tern

I'm trying to get tern autocomplete working. I'm on OSX 10.10

Stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/FDSc2Ymv

I found this link maybe regarding this issue: https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/issues/309

My version of popup is latest (0.5.1)

Here is a segment of what my init.el looks like

```
;; JavaScript Mode
(require 'js2-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode))
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook (lambda () (tern-mode t)))
(eval-after-load 'tern
   '(progn
     (require 'tern-auto-complete)
     (tern-ac-setup)))
```

Any ideas?
I've tried directly copying the repo, adding it to the load path, so I'm inclined to believe it's something with my auto-complete.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is actually your problem, but I had this error until i added a .tern-project file to my project root directory.

```
{
  "plugins": {
    "node": {
    }
  }
}
```